# Should all third party dependencies be injected into angular.module?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Let's say I'm using both Angular UI and a third party library that just has a single directive. Even though one is clearly much, much larger than the other, do they both get equal billing under the dependency portion of angular.module? Or can I simply inject the smaller dependency into the controller where I need to use it?

exampleapp.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'angular-ui',
  'thirdpartylib'
  ]);
```

What is the best practice for injecting libraries only where needed?

Answer (score 0):

I separate my application into different modules:

```
angular.module("App.controllers", []);
angular.module("App.services", ["ngResource"]);
angular.module("App.directives", []);
angular.module("App.filters", []);
angular.module("App.constants", []);
angular.module("App", [
    "ngRoute",
    "App.services",
    "App.directives",
    "App.filters",
    "App.controllers",
    "App.constants"
]);
```

Since the `ngResource` is only used in the `App.services` module there's no need inserting it in the whole application.

When I need to create a controller, I just do:

```
angular.module("App.controllers").controller("NewController",["$scope", function($scope){


}]);
```

To keep it simple, I would add the module in the app "submodules"(when you first create the module like I do in the `App.services`) so you keep your code clean. There's no need of injecting the module in other places if you won't use it.

check out [ngBoilerplate](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp#readme)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lazy load, you must inject to whicht controllers, directives, services etc when script loaded to the page. Else, there is no inconvenience for injecting in app definition. It doesn't run while called.